# How to get Id number or code of particular city?

Tags: android, google-maps

when user chooses particular city from spinner, maps will be opened, so user can choose particular place from the chosen city. If user goes outside of the chosen city, there will be a toast like “not your city”. I need unique id number of the city which is shown on map and to compare with city selected on on spinner

Comment: Are you using the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/)? If not, what is meant by "place"? Just any geographical coordinate?

Comment: Google Places API provides id for the number of places that are located in the same city. But i just need id for city only, not places inside of it. Google Map shows different names for the same city like “moscow” and “moskva”. That is why i need unique id number of it

Comment: In other words: given a location, you want to check it is within a given city right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: @JohonAlimov Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google Maps API does not release information on city bounds (i.e. the polygon defining the boundaries of the city). I would suggest using OpenStreetMap, which does release this data, and has unique ID numbers for any city/region/country/etc. [Here is a search engine](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=178508484) built using OSM, if you look at the URL, you can see there is a unique ID associated with the city (in this case, New York). And [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) is the wiki/documentation on how to use OSM with Android.

EDIT: Also [see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183248/how-to-get-polygon-boundaries-of-city-in-json-from-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out what is the [place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) for the city using the reverse geocoding request for coordinates inside the city and specifying the result type equals to locality.

For example, the coordinate 55.710424,37.682381 is located inside Moscow, so the reverse geocoding with result type

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.710424%2C37.682381&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

will return the following response

```
{
"results":[
  {
    "address_components":[
      {
        "long_name":"Moscow",
        "short_name":"Moscow",
        "types":[
          "locality","political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name":"Moskva",
        "short_name":"Moskva",
        "types":[
          "administrative_area_level_2","political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name":"Moscow",
        "short_name":"Moscow",
        "types":[
          "administrative_area_level_1","political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name":"Russia",
        "short_name":"RU",
        "types":[
          "country","political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address":"Moscow, Russia",
    "geometry":{
      "bounds":{
        "northeast":{
          "lat":56.009657,"lng":37.9456611
        },
        "southwest":{
          "lat":55.48992699999999,"lng":37.3193289
        }
      },
      "location":{
        "lat":55.755826,"lng":37.6172999
      },
      "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport":{
        "northeast":{
          "lat":56.009657,"lng":37.9456611
        },
        "southwest":{
          "lat":55.48992699999999,"lng":37.3193289
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id":"ChIJybDUc_xKtUYRTM9XV8zWRD0",
    "types":[
      "locality","political"
    ]
  }
],
"status":"OK"
}
```

and you can see that the place ID of Moscow is `ChIJybDUc_xKtUYRTM9XV8zWRD0`.

[image]

You can use this place ID in conjunction to reverse geocoding with locality result type to check if coordinate is located inside the given city.

For example, coordinate 55.586107,38.229675 is outside of Moscow boundaries and reverse geocoding

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.586107%2C38.229675&language=en&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

will give you a different locality with place ID `ChIJu_L0awrASkER7yCl6FLZFLE` which is a city 'Ramenskoye, Moscow Oblast, Russia'.

[image]

I hope you find this information useful.